# How to find the weighted average between two dates?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, sumproduct

I have a spreadsheet that has a list of dollar amounts and percentages, with each amount tied to a date. I'm currently calculating the sumproduct of the dollars and percentages, but the range is fixed. I'd like to be able to sort and filter the data and still return an accurate sumproduct.

As an example, for the data below, I'd like to conditionally sumproduct dates between 12/31/2017 and 1/1/2019. This would then exclude the two latter dates.

```
Date / Dollars / Percent

12/21/18 / $14.93 / 3.75%

12/27/18 / $8.25 / 0.46%

1/4/19 / $14.93 / 3.03%

1/10/19 / $8.25 / 0.98%
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(FILTER(B2:C, A2:A > DATEVALUE("31/12/2017"), 
                         A2:A < DATEVALUE("1/1/2019")))
```

[image]